# jqGrid doesn't rise ondblClickRow event when filter applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

This is event calling filtering while typing:

```
$("#txtPickItem").change(function (e) { doSearchPick(); });
```

This is my jqGrid:

```
$("#gridChooseItems").GridUnload();
jQuery("#gridChooseItems").jqGrid({
    url: 'MyURL', datatype: "JSON",
    colNames: ['id', 'Group', 'Source order'...],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'del', index: ' ', width: 28, hidden: true },
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
        { name: 'Group', index: 'Group', hidden: true },
        { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 180 }...
    ],
    loadComplete: function () { if ($("#txtPickItem").val()) { setTimeout('doSearchPick();', 100); } },
    rowNum: 25, rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
    pager: '#pagerChooseItems',
    sortname: 'id',
    ondblClickRow: function (id) { AddItem(id); },
    height: 580,
    width: 1050,
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Available items"
});
```

My filtering function:

```
function doSearchPick() {
    var grid = $("#gridChooseItems");
    var filter = {
        "groupOp": "AND", "rules":
            [
                { "field": "Supplier", "op": "cn", "data": $("#txtPickItem").val() }
            ]
    };
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { filters: filter } });
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
}
```

I have to reload grid after doubleclick and apply filter so previously double clicked item is not in grid anymore (many things happens in between).

When `$("#txtPickItem")` is empty, ondblClickRow and everything works fine, filtering works fine too.

Problem is that when some text is contained in txtPickItem, ondblClickRow doesn't fire and I don't understand why. I need this ondblClickRow event desperately.

EDIT:

AddItem function works fine as everything else if `$("#txtPickItem")` is empty

```
function AddItem(id) {
    pData = {}
    pData["ItemID"] = id;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: pData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "msg1") {
                PopulatePickGridItems(); //fill some other grid
            }

            else if (data == "msg2") {
                $("#divMsg").html("<ul><li>err1. msg.</li></ul>")
                $('#dlgMsg').dialog('open');
            }
            else {
                $("#divMsg").html("<ul><li>err2. msg.</li></ul>")
                $('#dlgMsg').dialog('open');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's strange that you use `setTimeout('doSearchPick();', 100);` in `loadComplete` instead of `setTimeout(function () { doSearchPick(); }, 100);`. Another unknown thing. You wrote about problems in `ondblClickRow ` callback, but it includes just the call of `AddItem` which code you didn't posted. Could you add the code too?

Comment: @Oleg edited as you requested

Comment: I don't see any relation of `AddItem` to `$("#txtPickItem")`. Why `AddItem` should not work? A little strand that you use `AddItem` for functions, but functions with the first capital name are reserved for constructors. You see in the color of the text that the function should have anothe meaning. It's not the reason of your problem, but it makes difficult to read your code. In the same way one should just use `data: { ItemID: id }` instead of `pData = {}` (without `;`) and `pData["ItemID"] = id;` (instead of `pData.ItemID = id;`). **What exactly not work in `ondblClickRow` callback?**

Comment: @oleg AddItem works. Event doesn't rise.

Comment: It seems me very strange. Do you have the demo which demonstrates the problem? One need to debug it.

Comment: @oleg Data I provided are more than sufficient for one who know the answer

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem which you describe?

Comment: I believe, you understand.